# how do i control the length of an array

Tags: c

My problem is that array b can take more than 12 characters and if that happends it prints out only array b with no errors

```
{
int i=12;
char a[i] ,b[i];
printf("give string with no more than 12 characters ");
scanf("%s",a);
printf("give second string with no more than 12 characters\n");
scanf("%s",b);
if(a[i]>i || b[i]>i){
    printf("try again cause you typed more than 12\n");
    printf("first \n");
    scanf("%s",a);
    printf("second \n");
    scanf("%s",b);
    }
printf("you gave %s & %s \n",a,b);
```

I expect the output "try again cause you typed more than 12"
when i type more than 12 characters

Comment: This is one reason why `scanf` is so dangerous.  It's reading characters from the user, and you haven't told it that it's not allowed to read more than 12 characters.  You could use `scanf("%11s", ...)`, but it's hard to construct that format string from your variable `i`.

Comment: What does `if (a[i] > i || b[i] > i) { ...` do?

Comment: There is no point of checking whether user has inputted more than 12 characters as you have already hit UB by reading out of bound. The point is you need to restrict the user from entering 12 chars.

Comment: `if(a[i] > i)`  does not do what you think it does. Indeed, attempting to reference `a[i]` is an error.  `a` is an array with 12 elements, so you can read from `a[0]` through `a[11]`.  If you want the length of the string in `a`, you can use `strlen(a)`.  The size of `a` is fixed at 12.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is difficult with scanf because of problems capturing the newline character.
With `fgets` the newline is captured as part of the char array. Just check if the input contains a newline and you know that there are no more characters to read.
There are useful functions in `string.h` that would make this code much shorter such as `strchr` and `strcspn`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void) {
    char a[14];
    char b[14];
    int toolong = 1;

    do {
        int retry = 0;//not retry
        toolong = 1;//too long
        printf ( "give string with no more than 12 characters ");
        if ( fgets ( a, sizeof a, stdin)) {//read a line
            int each = 0;
            while ( a[each]) {
                if ( '\n' == a[each]) {//found a newline
                    if ( ! retry) {//not retry
                        toolong = 0;//not too long
                        a[each] = 0;//remove newline
                    }
                    else {
                        printf ( "try again cause you typed more than 12\n");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                each++;
                if ( ! a[each]) {//found zero terminator at end of line
                    if ( ! fgets ( a, sizeof a, stdin)) {//read more to find newline
                        fprintf ( stderr, "fgets EOF\n");
                        return 0;
                    }
                    each = 0;//start over at [0]
                    retry = 1;//retry
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "fgets EOF\n");
            return 0;
        }
    } while ( toolong);

    do {
        int retry = 0;
        toolong = 1;
        printf ( "give second string with no more than 12 characters ");
        if ( fgets ( b, sizeof b, stdin)) {
            int each = 0;
            while ( b[each]) {
                if ( '\n' == b[each]) {
                    if ( ! retry) {
                        toolong = 0;
                        b[each] = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        printf ( "try again cause you typed more than 12\n");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                each++;
                if ( ! b[each]) {
                    if ( ! fgets ( b, sizeof b, stdin)) {
                        fprintf ( stderr, "fgets EOF\n");
                        return 0;
                    }
                    each = 0;
                    retry = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "fgets EOF\n");
            return 0;
        }
    } while ( toolong);

    printf ( "you gave %s & %s\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Using `string.h` and putting the duplicate code in a function makes it much shorter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strlimit ( char *str, int limit) {
    int toolong = 1;

    do {
        toolong = 0;// not too long
        printf ( "give string with no more than 12 characters ");
        if ( fgets ( str, limit, stdin)) {//read a line
            if ( ! strchr ( str, '\n')) {//no newline
                while ( ! strchr ( str, '\n')) {//look for newline
                    fgets ( str, limit, stdin);//read more
                }
                toolong = 1;// too long
                printf ( "try again cause you typed more than 12\n");
            }
            str[strcspn ( str, "\n")] = 0;//remove newline
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "fgets EOF\n");
            return NULL;
        }
    } while ( toolong);

    return str;
}

int main( void) {
    char a[14];
    char b[14];

    if ( ! strlimit ( a, sizeof a)) {
        return 0;
    }

    if ( ! strlimit ( b, sizeof b)) {
        return 0;
    }

    printf ( "you gave %s & %s\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=12;
char a[i] ,b[i];
```

So arrays `a` and `b` each have 12 elements.

```
if(a[i]>i || b[i]>i){
```

Nothing has changed the value of `i`, so `i` is still 12. So `a[i]` is equivalent to `a[12]`. But since `a` only has 12 elements, there is no thirteenth element (since `a[0]` is the first element, `a[12]` is the thirteenth). So this is an attempt to access an entry in an array that doesn't exist.

If you want to detect whether or not a person enters more than 12 characters, you need code that can allow them to enter more than 12 characters. That's not what you've written.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to limit the number of characters read into `a` and `b`, not to check if the user entered too many characters after the fact (by which time the damage will already have been done).

There are several ways to do this.  One is to use an explicit width on the `%s` conversion specifier in the `scanf` call:

```
scanf( "%11s", a );
```

Another use to use `fgets` instead of `scanf`:

```
fgets( a, sizeof a, stdin);
```

Both will prevent more than 11 characters being read into `a`, and will add the 0-terminator.

*However*, if the user typed 12 or more characters, those extra characters will still be waiting in the input stream, which will be picked up by your next input operation, which is probably not what you want.  You'll need to scrub the input stream if that's the case.  One approach is to read and discard any non-whitespace characters immediately after your input operation:

```
if ( fgets( a, sizeof a, stdin ) != NULL ) // if ( scanf( "%11s", a ) == 1 )
{
  // Successfully read into a
  // Scrub any non-whitespace characters remaining in the input stream
  int c;
  while ( !isspace( c = getchar() ) )
    ; // empty loop body
  if ( c != EOF ) 
    ungetc( c, stdin );
}
else
{
  // error on input
}
```

The `while` loop will keep reading individual characters from the input stream until it sees a whitespace character.  If we do read a whitespace character, we push it back onto the input stream.